# how to enable role in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

i am trying to enable roles in asp.net but,i am getting few errors and after trying my best i am not able to get them resolved.

I am new to visual studio interface. I tried creating a login page as ASP.NET web application. Then as we have to configure the page to connect to the database to retrieve user details, i clicked on the ASP.NET configuration under Website control.. I was taken to the configuration page with three tabs.. Security was the tab that i was supposed to configure.. But i am not able to go through to the security tab. I get the following error message.

> There is a problem with your selected
>   data store. This can be caused by an
>   invalid server name or credentials, or
>   by insufficient permission. It can
>   also be caused by the role manager
>   feature not being enabled. Click the
>   button below to be redirected to a
>   page where you can choose a new data
>   store. The following message may help
>   in diagnosing the problem: Unable to
>   connect to SQL Server database.

I also clicked on the button to select a new data store, but there was only one default data store available.

i enabled my role manager tag to true,but again i am facing the same problem

Any process to configure the security tab would be helpful.

Comment: i am creating a website in which i want to create certain roles for users and provide authentication etc....i am new to all this and know a bit about mvc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use steps below:

1. Configure your database in order to maintain ASP.NET Application Services. [You can see here how to do it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx)
2. Edit your web.config file. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx)
3. Go to ASP.NET Configuration Tool under Website control and create required roles.

Comment: i am unable to understand the configuration of web.config can you post some other links which are more hepful

Comment: There are 2 quite detailed articles how to configure and use Membership and Role providers in asp.net: http://odetocode.com/Articles/427.aspx,  http://odetocode.com/Articles/428.aspx

Comment: please let me know how can i use telerik controls of silverlight in my asp.net web application

Comment: Create silverlight project, then add reference to the assembly with teleric controls. You will be able to use these controls in your project and finally you will compile it and create .xap archive. Then you will just reference this archive in your markup. For example: 

  <asp:Silverlight ID="mySilverlightControlID" 
   runat="server" Source="~/ClientBin/MyControl.xap" 

   MinimumVersion="2.0.31005.0" />

Comment: thanks alot ...hope to get your help in my near projects also.

Comment: is there a need to do some changes in web config? i am getting an error that silverlight not a known element. my be due to some compilation error or web config is missing.

Comment: you have to register tag either in web.config (<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.SilverlightControls"
assembly="System.Web.Silverlight" />) or directly on page (<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Silverlight"
Namespace="System.Web.UI.SilverlightControls"
   TagPrefix="asp" %>).

Comment: No problem with help. I regulary visit this site if I have some free time

Comment: @Egor4eg - Yesterday before I posted this question I tried working through one of the odetocode articles, and just don't have the background on what specifically to change from their web.config example to work with my setup. Too new to doing this type of work.