# Unable To add membership authentication to website

Tags: asp.net, membership

I created a website named xmlquiz. I want to authenticate it with membership, but when I am going to security tab(Website->ASP.Net Configuration->security) I am getting an error as follows.

```
There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid
server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the
role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a   
page where you can choose a new data store.

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.
```

I am trying following code in web.config

`<rolemember enable="true">` and run ASPNET_REGSQL.exe but it does not work.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you post the configuration of ConnectionString

Comment: i am not adding any coonection string in configuration file i am new in asp.net please guide me..

Comment: try this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281573/ASP-NET-Membership-and-Role-Provider

Comment: what is the reason for that error?

Comment: have you created the database for membership? could you connect it in visual studio?

Comment: no i am not created database ...i follow your article and stuck in following line what is "cnn" <membership defaultProvider="Demo">
    <providers>
      <add name="Demo_MemberShipProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
          connectionStringName="cnn"</providers>
  </membership>

Comment: actually, the above link skip the creation of database, forget it. cnn is the name of connectionstring which generated in web.config

Answer (score 0):

I find another post with the same problem of yours,

[how to enable role in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949460/how-to-enable-role-in-asp-net)

I hope to see your **web.config** (please check it with the link above) and could you find the database files in AppData Folder(I think)

if I understand correctly, questionid should come from xml base and userid could be get by the current user logged in. With the code below:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(); 
Guid userId = (Guid)(user.ProviderUserKey);
```

to get the userId.

I don't know your xml schema so I can't tell you how to get questionId and correct result.

Comment: Thank You for Your Time ...It Works..Thank you once again.

Comment: sir i want to ask another question to you..i am trying to build xml base quiz and result data should store in sql server database,how should i store correct anwser with userid and questionid in database from xml file

Comment: I modified the answer. If you think this answer helps, please mark it as the answer

Comment: i want according to user all solved correct answer should store in to database