# Security in asp.net configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Why I am getting following error.When i click on security in asp.net configuration

There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.

SQL SERVER is not installed in my machine.IS I installed sql server in my  machine.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:
[how to enable role in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949460/how-to-enable-role-in-asp-net)

> 1. Configure your database in order to maintain ASP.NET Application Services. You can see it here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx
> 2. Edit your web.config file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx
> 3. Go to ASP.NET Configuration Tool under Website control and create required roles.

If you still didn't manage to handle it, you can have a look at this article:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1088928.aspx?Ack+The+old+There+is+a+problem+with+your+selected+data+store+This+can+be+caused+by+an+invalid+server+name+or+credentials+error+message+in+trying+to+change+my+provider+from+SQLExpress+to+SQL2K+

Comment: can u further explain

Comment: I want this through asp.net configuration membership screen

Comment: Cyril Durand, No problem, just wanted to give credit to the original author of the answer.
Here it goes:

1. Configure your database in order to maintain ASP.NET Application Services. You can see it here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx

2. Edit your web.config file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx

3. Go to ASP.NET Configuration Tool under Website control and create required roles.

4. If you still didn't manage to handle it, you can have a look at this article:

Comment: @FelixAv : you can edit your post rather than adding this in another comment.